# Plot inverse function in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

`pgfplots` is not quite comfortable plotting `sqrt(x)` near `x=0`. The graphic can be improved by setting `samples=2000` (not less), but this seems overkill to me.

Is there a way to plot x as a function of y, while keeping the x axis horizontal and the y axis vertical? This would solve the issue of plotting `sqrt(x)` by simply replacing it with `x=y^2`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot[] {sqrt(x)};
  \addplot[] {-sqrt(x)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use a parametrized plot:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot[red, ultra thick] (x*x,x);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just for a comparison purpose how PSTricks does it with `swapaxes` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(5,5)
\psaxes[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(5,5)
\parabola[linecolor=blue](2,4)(0,0)
\parabola[linecolor=red,swapaxes](2,4)(0,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Note:

```
\parabola[linecolor=red,swapaxes](2,4)(0,0)
```

passes through the point `(2,4)` with a critical point `(0,0)`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to do the same in pgfplots?

Comment: @nemarona: If such an option does not exist in pgf/tikz, then you might have to use a transformation (rotation is enough).

Comment: "swap axes" in pgfplots means to use a parametric plot as in the answer of Peter Grill - and exchanging the X and Y expressions manually.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Thank you for the useful information.

Answer (score 4):

Use rotation. Here is the minimal code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=-90]
    \draw[domain=-2:2] plot (\x,\x*\x);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Rotations are not inverse functions! E.g. y=x

Comment: @strpeter: Yes of course but nobody knows if you just see the image.

Comment: @strpeter: The problem is that the question is misleading so I just followed what the questioner wanted to get no matter his incorrect usage of the term "inverse function". I understand that inverse function must have a single value for each input.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the mathematics side of it, but I often use R to produce my graphics using [tikzDevice](http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=440).

R code (produces tex then graphic):

```
library(tikzDevice)
tikz('normal.tex', standAlone = TRUE, width=5, height=5)
x <- seq (-50, 50, length = 50)
xx <-x^2
plot(xx, type="l")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: One step more is needed to rotate the graph 90 degree clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzaxes(-1,-3)(5,3){$x$}{$y$}
\tzfnofy[blue,thick]{(\y)^2}[-2:2]{$f(y)=y^2$}[a] % function of y
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```