# pgfplots: Plot inverse function (function of y)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot, fpu

I am trying to plot the [Ramberg-Osgood-relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramberg%E2%80%93Osgood_relationship) for a specific material with pgfplots. The relationship describes the stress-strain-curve, that is the stress as a function of the strain. The relationship itself is defined as the strain as a function of the stress:

```
strain(stress)=stress/modulus+0.002*(stress/yield stress)^n
```

I already found a [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72712/plot-inverse-function-in-pgfplots) which describes plotting inverse functions, so plot x as a function of y.

However, everything I tried results in an error, either *Dimension too large* by TikZ, *Illegal unit of measure* with fpu as in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/pgfplots-and-calculations-without-fpu-dimension-too-large-with-fpu-illegal) or the wrong function with gnuplot.

Here are the MWE's for the things I tried:

- Plain pgfplots:

  ```
  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepackage{siunitx}

  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

  \begin{document}

  \pgfplotsset{stressstrainset/.style={%
  axis lines=center,
  xlabel={$\varepsilon$ $\left[\si{\percent}\right]$},
  ylabel={$\sigma$ $\left[\si{\MPa}\right]$},
  restrict x to domain=0:15,
  restrict y to domain=0:775,
  xmin=0.0, xmax=  15,
  ymin=0.0, ymax= 775,
  samples=100,
  }}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\modulus{72400}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yield{325}
  \begin{axis}[stressstrainset]
  \addplot[black] (x/\modulus+0.002*(x/\yield)^15,x);
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
  ```

Results in:

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.21 \pgfmathsetmacro\modulus{72400}
```

- pgfplots with fpu:

  ```
  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepackage{siunitx}

  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

  \begin{document}

  \pgfplotsset{stressstrainset/.style={%
  axis lines=center,
  xlabel={$\varepsilon$ $\left[\si{\percent}\right]$},
  ylabel={$\sigma$ $\left[\si{\MPa}\right]$},
  restrict x to domain=0:15,
  restrict y to domain=0:775,
  xmin=0.0, xmax=  15,
  ymin=0.0, ymax= 775,
  samples=100,
  }}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\modulus{72400}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yield{325}
  \begin{axis}[stressstrainset]
  \addplot[black] (x/\modulus+0.002*(x/\yield)^15,x);
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
  ```

Results in:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

- pgfplots with gnuplot:

  ```
  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepackage{siunitx}

  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

  \begin{document}

  \pgfplotsset{stressstrainset/.style={%
  axis lines=center,
  xlabel={$\varepsilon$ $\left[\si{\percent}\right]$},
  ylabel={$\sigma$ $\left[\si{\MPa}\right]$},
  restrict x to domain=0:15,
  restrict y to domain=0:775,
  xmin=0.0, xmax=  15,
  ymin=0.0, ymax= 775,
  samples=100,
  }}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[stressstrainset]
  \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot,id=nfive, mark=none, draw=black]{
  set xrange  [0:15];
  modulus = 72400;
  yield   = 325;
  h(x)=(x/modulus+0.002*(x/yield)^15);
  plot h(x),x
  };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
  ```

Gives me a result which is obviously wrong.

### Edit

I also tried using GPa as unit for the stress, but I would like to set up the chart in the MPa-System since the rest of my document uses it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{stressstrainset/.style={%
axis lines=center,
xlabel={$\varepsilon$ $\left[-\right]$},
ylabel={$\sigma$ $\left[\si{\GPa}\right]$},
restrict x to domain=0:0.15,
restrict y to domain=0:0.775,
xmin=0.0, xmax=  0.15,
ymin=0.0, ymax= 0.775,
samples=1000,
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\modulus{72.400}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yield{0.325}
\begin{axis}[stressstrainset]
\addplot[black] (x/\modulus+0.002*(x/\yield)^15,x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Edit2

Thanks to @Christian's answer, there is a running version of the chart. However, I found out, that I need to define the strains, thus the x-axis, not in percent, but in the actual decimal value in order to obtain the correct graph.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{stressstrainset/.style={%
axis lines=center,
xlabel={$\varepsilon$ $\left[-\right]$},
ylabel={$\sigma$ $\left[\si{\MPa}\right]$},
domain=0:775,
xmin=0.0, xmax= 0.15,
ymin=0.0, ymax= 775,
samples=100,
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\modulus{72400}
\def\yield{325}
\begin{axis}[stressstrainset]
\addplot[gray, dashed] ({x/\modulus},x);
\addplot[black] ({x/\modulus+0.002*(x/\yield)^15},x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now again, there is the problem that I do get the error

```
! Dimension too large.
```

for the second addplot, but only if the exponent is >10. Is the value getting too small?

Can someone please explain how I can set up this chart correctly?

Comment: One possible problem with first and second example is that the calculations should not exceed ±16383.99999 (`\modulus{72400}` seems to be a direct violation of this rule). This limitation, if I'm not so wrong, is inherited from `TeX`.

Comment: thx @Pouya, that is why I tried the workaround with fpu

Comment: The easiest partial answer is to switch your stress axis to units of GPa, and scale all stress numbers down by a factor of 1000. You'll probably need to increase your samples from 100 to 1000 as well. Working on how to change the y axis labels back to units of MPa, but haven't finished that yet.

Comment: you could also try avoiding having 72400 in memory at once by using `x/72400=x/72.4/1000`

Comment: Fixed the GPa to MPa problem now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already explained in some comment, `\pgfmathsetmacro{72400}` is unsupported by PGF (in fact, my system accepts it without problems - apparently something has changed in PGF CVS).

Nevertheless, you do not need `\pgfmathsetmacro` just to declare a constant; it is much simpler to write `\def\MACRO{<constant>}` (or use `\newcommand\MACRO{<constant>}` which should be the same).

Then you need to assign a `domain`. The key(s) `restrict * to domain` are no definition how to sample points; they can be used to exclude already sampled points from the region of interest. In your case, you would define `domain=775` and omit the `restrict * to domain`.

Finally, math expressions in parametric plots need extra curly braces if they contain other round braces. In other words, use `({x/\modulus+0.002*(x/\yield)^15},x)` to avoid confusion with the round braces (TeX cannot automatically balance them, it can only balance curly braces).

Taking this together, I arrive at the following modification of your first plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{stressstrainset/.style={%
axis lines=center,
xlabel={$\varepsilon$},
ylabel={$\sigma$},
%restrict x to domain=0:15,
domain=0:775,
xmin=0.0, xmax=  15,
ymin=0.0, ymax= 775,
samples=100,
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\modulus{72400}
\def\yield{325}
\begin{axis}[stressstrainset]
\addplot[black] ({x/\modulus+0.002*(x/\yield)^15},x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. However, I found out, that I have to define my x-axis (strains) not in percent but in the actual decimal value to obtain the correct chart. This results in another *Dimensions too large*-Error. I updated my questions accordingly.

Comment: The dimensions too large errors happen if and only if the axis limits (`xmin` and friends) show a much _smaller_ portion than the data range. In order to fix these items, you need to add `restrict x to domain=0:0.3` or something like that. The precise value does not matter, it is just required that the difference between data range and axis range is "reasonably small". Perhaps I should implement automatic support for this case...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try that as soon as the construction workers turn the power back on in my office. An automatic check would be helpful I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what worked for me on TeX Live 2013:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{stressstrainset/.style={%
axis lines=center,
xlabel={$\varepsilon$ $\left[\si{\percent}\right]$},
ylabel={$\sigma$ $\left[\si{\MPa}\right]$},
restrict x to domain=0:15,
restrict y to domain=0:0.775, % GPa
xmin=0.0, xmax=  15,
ymin=0.0, ymax= 0.775, % GPa
samples=1000,
%scaled y ticks=false,
yticklabels={0, 0, 200, 400, 600} % MPa
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\modulus{72.400} % GPa
\pgfmathsetmacro\yield{0.325} % GPa
\begin{axis}[stressstrainset]
\addplot[black] (x/\modulus+0.002*(x/\yield)^15,x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Partly solved.) I have drawn almost perfect straight line without significant y-intercept change! Even those values look suspiciously...

Well, I don't know exactly how to set the parameters for this particular task, but I wasn't limited in calculations as Lua was on the run. It might be useful to know this way for similar tasks in a long run. Lua can be even improved by the BigNum and BigRat libraries, http://oss.digirati.com.br/luabignum/. I was inspired by this article, http://www.unirioja.es/cu/jvarona/downloads/numerical-methods-luatex.pdf, to try this task regardless the results. As an exercise I also listed the coordinates as an immediate feedback if the results are what they should be.

```
%! lualatex inverse.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{luacode}
\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\def\myxmin{0}
\def\myxmax{15}
\def\mysamples{100}
\def\mymodulus{72400} % /1000?
\def\myyield{325} % /1000?

\pgfplotsset{stressstrainset/.style={%
  axis lines=center,
  xlabel={Strain $\varepsilon$ $\left[\si{\percent}\right]$},
  ylabel={Stress $\sigma$ $\left[\si{\MPa}\right]$},
  restrict x to domain=0:\myxmax,
  restrict y to domain=0:775, % /1000?
  xmin=\myxmin, xmax=\myxmax,
  ymin=0.0, ymax=775, % /1000?
  samples=\mysamples,
  }}

\begin{luacode*}
-- Round me...
-- http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleRound
function round(num, idp)
  local mult=10^(idp or 0)
  return math.floor(num*mult+0.5)/mult
end

-- Compute me...
function computeme(xmin,xmax,samples,modulus,yield)
  local step=(xmax-xmin)/(samples-1)
  local x=xmin
  local y
  local mystring=""
  tex.sprint("\\begin{tikzpicture}")
  tex.sprint("\\begin{axis}[stressstrainset])")
  tex.sprint("\\addplot[black] coordinates {")
  for i=1,samples do
    y=1000000*(x/modulus+0.002*(x/yield)^15)
    mystring=mystring.."("..round(x,2)..","..round(y,2)..") "
    x=x+step
  end
tex.sprint(mystring) -- values in the graph
tex.sprint("};")
tex.sprint("\\end{axis}")
tex.sprint("\\end{tikzpicture}\\par")
tex.sprint(mystring) -- paper
end
\end{luacode*}

% Draw and show me...
\directlua{computeme(\myxmin, \myxmax, \mysamples, \mymodulus, \myyield)}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]