# Horizontal parabola

Tags: plot

How does one draw a horizontal parabola, left or right oriented?
I can easily draw:

```
\draw[blue, line width=1.75pt, domain=-2.00 : 3.00, samples=1500] plot[smooth](\x, {\x*\x - \x - 2});
```

and even trick a horizontal parabola in origin using two radicals:

```
\draw[magenta, line width=1.75pt, domain={0.00}:{3.0}, samples=1500] plot[smooth]( \x, {pow(\x, 0.5)} );
\draw[magenta, line width=1.75pt, domain={0.00}:{3.0}, samples=1500] plot[smooth]( \x, {- pow(\x, 0.5)} );
```

But I cannot make it do this (true horizontal parabola):

```
\draw[red, line width=1.75pt, domain={-4.10}:{4.0}, samples=500] plot[smooth]( \y, {\y*\y - \y - 2} );
```

Any idea?
Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools} %includes amsmath
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, cap=round]

\draw[->] (-4.0,0) -- (4.0,0); % Ox
\node[below] at (4.0, 0.0) {\textit{x}};
\node at (-0.2,-0.3) {\textit{0}};
\draw[->] (0,-4.0) -- (0,4.0); % Oy
\node[left] at (0.0,4.0) {\textit{f(x)}};
\filldraw [red] (0.00, 0.00) circle(3pt);

\draw[blue, line width=1.75pt, domain=-2.00 : 3.00, samples=1500] plot[smooth](\x, {\x*\x - \x - 2});
%\draw[red, line width=1.75pt, domain={-4.10}:{4.0}, samples=500] plot[smooth]( \y, {\y*\y - \y - 2} );

\draw[magenta, line width=1.75pt, domain={0.00}:{3.0}, samples=1500] plot[smooth]( \x, {pow(\x, 0.5)} );
\draw[magenta, line width=1.75pt, domain={0.00}:{3.0}, samples=1500] plot[smooth]( \x, {- pow(\x, 0.5)} );

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apply `rotate=90` or `rotate=270` to one of the vertical ones.

Comment: [Parameterize it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72718/89497) `\draw[red, line width=1.75pt, domain={-4.10}:{4.0}, samples=500] plot[smooth]({\x*\x - \x - 2},\x );`

Comment: @Guho You should turn your comment into a proper answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Looks like @jarauh beat me to it. The link I posted in the comment has your proposed method, parameterization, and `swapaxes`.

Comment: @Guho Thank you, I am using your one-liner for the solution to this question -- if you make it an answer I will flag it accordingly. I did not know you can parametrize things just by switching the order around, awesome! Thank you all for your answers, but I am not that advanced, and right now I can't spend as much time as I would like studying these tikz and all the plotting routines. But I am saving them for later study, thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous approaches, as summarized by the answers provided in [Plot inverse function in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72712/89497).

Given your format, you could just switch the order of the arguments (and substitute `\x` for `\y`):

```
\draw[red, line width=1.75pt, domain={-4.10}:{4.0}, samples=500] plot[smooth]({\x*\x - \x - 2},\x );
```

which, if inserted in place of the commented line in your MWE, yields

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually not too difficult (if I understood correctly what you want):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[domain=-10:10,samples=50] ({x^2},{x});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the parabola with equation $x=y^2-y-2$, with `pst-plot`, you have `\parametricplot{init}{end}{f(t) | g(t)}`:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pst-plot, pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\psset{algebraic=true, arrowsize=3pt,arrowinset=0.15, plotpoints=500, linecolor=LightSteelBlue3}
\begin{pspicture*}(-3,-4)(8,4.5)
    \psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none, arrows=->](0,0)(-3,-4)(8,4.5)[$x$, -110][$y$,-135]
    \parametricplot[linecolor =IndianRed3, linewidth=1.2pt]{-4}{4}{t^2-t-2 | t}
    \dotnode[linecolor =IndianRed3](-2.25, 0.5){S}\pnodes(-2.25,0){Sx}(0,0.5){Sy}
    \psset{linewidth = 0.4pt, linestyle=dashed}
    \ncline{S}{Sx}\ncline{S}{Sy}
    \uput[d](Sx){$-\frac52$}\uput[r](Sy){$1$}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]